# Validate format specifiers in _snprintf - C++

Tags: c++, string, validation, format

In one of my projects I have proprietary string class(by name `class stringXYZ`) which manages all the string operations. But due to its drawbacks we wanted to replace it with `std::string`. We are done with replacing. The problem is `stringXYZ` has a `operator const char*()` overloaded so that whenever I give `stringXYZ` to any of `printf`, `sprintf`, `_snprintf` it turns to `char*`. We do not have such feature in `std::string`. Even Microsoft's compiler is also unable to find issues like the following:

```
char szBuff[255] = {0};
std::string strErr = "Improper arguments";

_snprintf(szBuff, sizeof(szBuff), "Error = %s", strErr);
```

Previously as `stringXYZ` class has `const char*` operator overloaded, `strErr` used to convert properly. But now as I moved to `std::string` no way I can detect this error. One option is to change the name of the variable from `strErr` to `strErr123`, compile and validate format specifiers. But it takes much long time as we have many string variables. I went for static code analyzers and found *FlawFinder* to be useful for my case. But stuck with installation of it as I am running a windows machine. Suggest me some free/open-source static code analyzers for validating format specifiers or some other method through which I can validate format strings.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `std::string::c_str()` at these places.

Comment: It's true that i can use 'std::string::c_str()' at these places, but the problem is finding them. I have a very huge code base and it will be very difficult for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you use g++ compiler, you got:

> error: cannot pass objects of non-trivially-copyable type 'std::string {aka class std::basic_string}' through '...'

or

> warning: format '%s' expects argument of type 'char*' [-Wformat=]

clang++ has similar warning/error for that.

Notice that even if `stringXYZ` has a `operator const char*`, it is implementation defined how *non-trivially-copyable type* are passed through ellipsis (...).